# How do I use an If DEBUG statement in C# without the IDE thinking code is unreachable?

Tags: c#, warnings, suppress-warnings, compiler-directives

I've got some code that needs to work slightly differently in debug and release modes. It has a constant called `PrettyPrint` that is set to `true` in some modes and `false` in others, and I sometimes change those around.

```
#if DEBUG
        public const bool PrettyPrint = true;
#else
        public const bool PrettyPrint = false;
#endif

// ...snip...
string start, end, comma, innerIndentation;
if (Printer.PrettyPrint) {
    innerIndentation = indentation + "  ";
    start = "[\n";
    end = indentation + "]";
    comma = ",\n" + innerIndentation;
} else {
    innerIndentation = "";
    start = "[";
    end = "]";
    comma = ",";
}
// Then do some prints using the initialized strings as constants
```

This works great, and the compiler is smart enough to optimize the `if` away. However, I get an annoying warning:

```
warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
```

Is there a way to avoid this warning without doing any of the following:

- using `#if` directly in the code - as it makes that part of the code quite ugly and I'd like to avoid `#if`s as much as possible.
- suppressing CS0162 for other cases - as I find that warning invaluable in finding broken code.

How do I use an `#if DEBUG` statement without the IDE believing that all code that follows is unreachable?

Comment: Replace *const* by *readonly*.

Comment: Has the compiler been tricked or something? I don't see any unreachable code

Comment: @Nicklamort, the compiler notices that `Printer.PrettyPrint` is a `const` and therefore will never change. i.e. that `if` statement will always evaluate to `true`, meaning the `else` portion will be unreachable (and the other way around when not in debug mode)

Comment: @BT So it has been 'tricked' then (since there are two declaration statements). Because it WILL change if DEBUG changes, no? Therefore the code is reachable

Comment: @Nicklamort: DEBUG is set at compile-time. So for a given compile, PrettyPrint will either always be true or always be false.

Comment: @Nick Lewis I know. The compiler should only give this warning for code that is unreachable, regardless if its between executions or not. For example, having code after a return statement. I would see that as a compiler bug, but that's just me

Comment: What do you mean by "between executions"? It won't matter how many times you run the code, the constant will either be always true or always false until the code is recompiled with a different DEBUG flag. Either way, one of the code blocks is unreachable, and it's entirely appropriate that the compiler warn you about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

`innerIndentation = Printer.PrettyPrint ? indentation + "  " : "";`

`start = Printer.PrettyPrint ? "[\n" : "[";`

`end = Printer.PrettyPrint ? indentation + "]" : "]";`

`comma = Printer.PrettyPrint ? ",\n" + innerIndentation : ",";`

But if it were me, I would just use an `#if` `#else`

Comment: That actually works quite well, and I still get compiler optimization so I decided to go with this route.

Answer (score 2):

While I currently don't have an idea how to work it into your code, you might find the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) helpful. You'd get around using preprocessor directives, but you might have to rework your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following to get round it.

```
Printer.PrettyPrint.Equals(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change `PrettyPrint` to a normal field instead of `const`.
You'll lose the compiler optimization, but that shouldn't matter.

I'm pretty sure you could also make it `readonly` without getting the warning; try it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the PrettyPrint from a const to a field.

```
#if DEBUG          
    public bool PrettyPrint = true;  
#else 
    public bool PrettyPrint = false;  
#endif
```